# Hard coding a value or cell reference when dragging down to adjacent rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have the below code in a vlookup 
`=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'[" & Inputs!B1 & "]Sheet1'!$B$3:$XFD$7"),2,FALSE)`

I want the `Inputs!B1` to stay as this value when i drag the formula down to the cell below but i need the first value `A2` to change as it should when dragged down.

Hope i've explained this properly

Thanks

Comment: [Absolute vs relative references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `$` between the `B` and the `1`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'[" & Inputs!B$1 & "]Sheet1'!$B$3:$XFD$7"),2,FALSE)
```

Comment: ... and remove the four **$**'s from the string constant `$B$3:$XFD$7`. (text doesn't change when dragged/copied/filled)

Comment: Of course, INDIRECT doesn't work on closed external references so this is likely a moot point.

Comment: Thanks for your help!